# Creating database connection using ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

I'm using ArcCatalog 10.2.2 which is installed on a Windows 2019 Server OS.  I'm having trouble creating a database connection.
Usually this is a very straight forward process.

Put in the server name under instance.
Database authentication.
When going to select the database it can see the different database on that server, so I know it can connect.

So it all looks fine right.

When I then double click the connect to browse it, usually on other Windows10 systems it takes maybe 30-60 seconds to establish the connection and download tables.

But this just sits there thinking... and thinking... and thinking.. its been over half an hour.  So there is something wrong, but I don't know where to start debugging it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds to me like network related problems. Have you tried using the server's IP address instead of its name? Or including the domain name?

Comment: You're mixing an old, retired application with a bright new operating system. You haven't specified the RDBMS, making it difficult to provide specific troubleshooting recommendations.

Comment: @Berend - I do kinda feel its network related also, but was kinda perplexed as Catalog could still read the different DBs local on the server.. so there is certainly some degree of traffic getting through.  I am chasing that avenue with our local IT department.. but I find responses come through here faster then our internal team.. haha..

Comment: @vince - the connecting database is an MSSQL 2012 server.  I didn't include that information because there are already 80 odd computers that connect to it without issue so I know its not related to the SQL DB server.

Comment: If the Microsoft library times out connecting to the SQL Server instance, then the problem is **certainly** related to the database server, no matter on which side of the communication link the error occurs.

Comment: @vince oh right.  is there a way I can work out if that is the issue? or how to resolve it?

Comment: It could be a Windows Framework issue, a driver issue, a connection library issue, a firewall issue,... 10.2.2 has been retired a while now, so it was never certified with 2019 Server. I do know that the connection drivers of newer ArcGIS releases are incapable to talking to older databases; if Win10 isn't supported by 10.2.2, you might need to downgrade the OS to the most recent one on the 80 working machines.